# Express $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ respectively

Tags: taylor-expansion

> What are the expansions of $\sin nx $ and $\cos nx$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ respectively? (here $n \in \mathbb N$).

Maybe  this  is  solved  problem  or  there  is  new  technique  to  answer  this  question
Tanhks

Comment: What does this have to do with Taylor Expansion?  (It could be something obvious I'm not seeing...)

Answer (score 3):

Let $T_n$ be the $n$th Chebychev polynomial, then

$$T_n(\cos(x))=\cos(nx)$$

For more information see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). The explicit formulas you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles).

Comment: And $\sin(nx) = \sin(x) U_n(\cos(x))$.  This doesn't quite expand $\sin(nx)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$, but you can substitute $\cos(x)^2 = 1 - \sin(x)^2$.  If $n$ is even, you still need one $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos(n x) =\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } i^{-k-n} \cos ^k(z) \sin ^{-k-n}(z) \left[\binom{-n}{k}+i^{2 n} \binom{n}{k} \sin ^{2 n}(z)\right]
$$
$$
\sin(n x) = \frac{1}{2 i}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } i^{-k-n} \cos ^k(z) \sin ^{-k-n}(z) \left[-\binom{-n}{k}+i^{2 n} \binom{n}{k} \sin ^{2 n}(z)\right]
$$
and
$$
\cos(n x) =\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } i^{-k-n} \cos ^k(z)  (1-\cos^2(x))^{(-k-n)/2} \left[\binom{-n}{k}+i^{2 n} \binom{n}{k} (1-\cos^2(x)) ^{ n}(z)\right]
$$
$$
\sin(n x) = \frac{1}{2 i}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } i^{-k-n} (1-\sin^2(z)) ^{k/2} \sin ^{-k-n}(z) \left[-\binom{-n}{k}+i^{2 n} \binom{n}{k} \sin ^{2 n}(z)\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note De'Moivre's formula:$$\cos(n x)+i\sin(n x) = (\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^n.$$ You can use the Binomial Theorem in the right to explore further and take either real or imaginary parts to isolate for cosine and sine as you require. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for further details.

**EDIT**

After the expansion you can substitute $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ to obtain an expression purely in terms of sines.

Comment: Ok  I  know  them   I  also  proved  but  I  need  only           sinnx ->sinx   expansion  not  include  cosine